# Paypal Payment Page not showing Cancel and Return to Paypal link

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

When my UAT site redirects user to Paypal Payment page then, ti does not provide and cancel link and after payment "Return URL" also not provided. Though I have set all 3 URLs - Cancel URL, Notify URL and Return URL.
It is working perfectly in local, but not on UAT.
[image: Paypal peyment page]

Answer (score 0):

If you have any problems displaying the cancel URL or the return URL in PayPal Payments Advanced, according to the Payflow Developer's Guide:
[Page 40 of Payflow Developer's Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf)

Payflow will ignore the cancel URL field that you entered in PayPal Manager if you select layout template C. To force Payflow to use the cancel URL field with layout template C, in PayPal Manager, add DISPLAY_URL | before your cancel URL.

```
Example: DISPLAY_URL | http://www.yoursite.com/home.php
```

If you have already made certain that you have entered the text for your Cancel URL and your Return URL in the PayPal Manager Hosted Checkout Pages, it is possible that you have not selected your layout in the Hosted Checkout Pages.
Make sure to go to Customize in the Hosted Checkout Pages and choose a layout (A,B, or C). Click Save and publish.

Just in case you need it, here are the instructions for fully setting up your Hosted Checkout Pages in PayPal Manager:
[Hosted Checkout Pages PayPal Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/)

Comment: I am not using the Classic APIS or REST aPIs, my client created a button of "Buy Now" and I am setting the "Return URL", " Notify URL" and "Cancel URL" in the hidden fields, I found out the issue today, the reason was that, since I was not using the API's, but my client has set the "Return URL" in Paypal Developer Rest API section and not in the Profile->My Selling Tools->Web Preferences section.

Comment: There is one other option for you within the payment button itself. If you go to step 3 within the payment button, you can specify the return URL and the Cancel URL. Just in case you need it, here is the link to the [PayPal Standard button Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_create-pps-buttons)